# Value not returning for switchmap 2nd http call - header error

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I'm trying to create a one time url link system for pw recovery. In order for it to work I am first sending an email to the user to reset password. What I'm trying to do is return the url created on backend to the `emailPasswordRecoveryAndStoreUrl(email: string)` so that I can POST that url to the backend and later check if it exists or not and redirect user to link has expired page if the link was clicked again.

Currently the

```
    return res.status(200).json({
        message: "url retrieved",
        url: generatedUrl
      })
```

gives `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`, but I can't figure out how to get the values to return without doing res.status(200) to return generatedUrl so that I can POST in the next http call.

I appreciate any help!

password-reset.service.ts

```
         sendEmail(email: string) {
        const password: PasswordReset = {
          email: email
        };
        console.log("Made It");
        return this.http.post<{
          url: string;
        }>(`http://localhost:3000/api/users/passwordreset`, password);
      }

      emailPasswordRecoveryAndStoreUrl(email: string) {
        const password: PasswordReset = {
          email: email
        };
        let url: string;
        return this.sendEmail(email).pipe(
          switchMap(value => {
            (url = value.url), console.log(url);
            return this.http.post(
              `http://localhost:3000/api/users/passwordurl`,
              url
            );
          })
        );
      }
```

app.js

```
app.post("/api/users/passwordreset/", function(req, res) {

    if (req.body.email !== undefined) {
      User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
      .then(user => {
        if(user){
          console.log("fetchedUser");
          console.log(user._id);
          var payload = {
            id: user._id,
            email: user.email
          };

           var secret = user.password + "-" + user.passwordCreated;
           console.log("THE SECRET IS: " + secret);
           var token = jwt.sign(payload, secret);
           console.log("payload");
           console.log(payload);


           let generatedUrl = "http://localhost:3000/resetpassword/" + payload.id + '/' + token


           var ses_mail = "From: 'Auction Site' <" + user.email+ ">\n";
           ses_mail = ses_mail + "To: " +user.email + "\n";
           ses_mail = ses_mail + "Subject: Password Reset Request\n";
           ses_mail = ses_mail + "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
           ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n";
           ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart\n";
           ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n\n";
           ses_mail = ses_mail + '<a href="http://localhost:3000/resetpassword/' + payload.id + '/' + token + '">Click here to reset password</a>';
         //  /:id/:token

           var params = {
             RawMessage: { Data: new Buffer.from(ses_mail) },
             Destinations: [user.email ],
             Source: "'AWS Tutorial Series' <" + user.email + ">'"

         };

           ses.sendRawEmail(params, function(err, data) {
            if(err) {

                res.send(err);
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                res.send(data);
            }
        })
        return res.status(200).json({
          message: "url retrieved",
          url: generatedUrl
        })
      }
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth failed"
          });
        }


      });


    } else {
      res.send("Email address is missing.");
    }
  });



app.post("/api/users/passwordurl", function(req, res) {

console.log("URL CALL");

});
```

Comment: You're calling `res.send(data)` before trying to send the 200 status and a json document. Choose what you want to do, either you send data, or you send json.

Comment: I see what you're referring to. That's part of the AWS SES sdk. I need that to go through for email to work I guess I'm trying to do both then in the same POST call. Is there anyway I can let aws send it's email and still return data to switchmap within same POST?

Comment: I don't see why sending data to the ExpressJS HTTP response would be needed to send an email.